# Need to charge my laptop from my powerback?

Tags: charging

I have a power bank that that has USB outputs for charging. But the cable I got with it only goes into my Samsung Galaxy S4. What I need is a cable to jam into that big ol' hole on my Toshiba laptop so I can charge my laptop down the park, do you feel me?

Comment: Nowhere near enough information. What powerback (sp?)? What Toshiba laptop? What makes you think you can charge your laptop with this?

Comment: toshiba satellite c50 and a Jackery giant.

Comment: That's not designed to charge your laptop. Your laptop won't charge through the USB port.

Comment: i don;'t want to charge it through the USB port. I want to charge it through the normal power jack. The USB goes  into the power bank.

Comment: It's not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot charge your laptop using this device.

> Can Jackery battery pack charge a laptop?
>
> No, Jackery products cannot charge a laptop since that requires much higher voltage.

-- [Jackery support](http://www.jackery.com/support/)